# Unexpected error while processing request: env missing required key SERVER_PORT

Tags: ruby, rack, thin, haproxy

I'm executing this on our staging server to start a Sinatra app:

```
envdir /etc/sv-env env RUBYLIB=./lib TZ=UTC VERBOSE=yes bundle exec thin --address 0.0.0.0 --port 9293 --environment development --rackup frontend.ru start
```

And it seems to start thin, but as soon as I `GET` the address, it shows the following error (on the console):

```
Unexpected error while processing request: env missing required key SERVER_PORT
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:20:in `assert'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:201:in `block in check_env'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:197:in `each'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:197:in `check_env'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:43:in `_call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/lint.rb:37:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:86:in `block in pre_process'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `catch'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:84:in `pre_process'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:53:in `process'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/eventmachine-1.0.3/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/backends/base.rb:73:in `start'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/server.rb:162:in `start'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:87:in `start'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:199:in `run_command'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/lib/thin/runner.rb:155:in `run!'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/thin-1.6.2/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
    /usr/local/bin/thin:19:in `load'
    /usr/local/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
```

I'm using thin 1.6.2.

The same command works on my development machine (both dev and staging are running Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS).
But one difference from dev is that staging is proxied through HAProxy.

Any idea?